# What's using my Grid Power?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-extra-utilities

The FTB HermitPack 1.10 modpack includes a mod called ExtraUtils2. In this mod, there is an energy system using grid power, where blocks wirelessly give/take grid power. In my world, I'm trying to figure out what's taking my grid power. I have removed all of the mechanical users and transport nodes I that I remember placing in my world, but something is still using 202 of my grid power, which is a significant amount of power. I think I must have missed some Grid Power-using blocks somewhere. How do I find what's using up the power, and where to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to find which blocks are using grid power, you will just have to look harder. One of my suggestions as to where to look might be your Angel Ring (that uses 32 GP)